# Rspec: Running Rspec v 2.99 in Rails but have v 3.0 installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, sinatra

So the Gemfile.lock of my Rails Framework sets my Rspec to v 2.99 while my computer runs 3.0.0. When I run my rspec test, I get:

```
/Users/MrChan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1051:in `load': cannot load such file -- /Users/MrChan/Desktop/matt/week_2/db-drill-ar-student-schema-challenge/source/ar-student-schema/db/spec/student_spec.rb (LoadError)
from /Users/MrChan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1051:in `block in load_spec_files'
from /Users/MrChan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1051:in `each'
from /Users/MrChan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1051:in `load_spec_files'
from /Users/MrChan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:97:in `setup'
from /Users/MrChan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:85:in `run'
from /Users/MrChan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:70:in `run'
from /Users/MrChan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:38:in `invoke'
from /Users/MrChan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/MrChan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
from /Users/MrChan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
```

I know that this may be a stretch, but does anyone have any ideas? I've taken a look at my rspec tests and tried changing be_true to be_truthy in line with Rspec v 3.0, but I'm still getting an error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error doesn't seem to be an Rspec version error. The first line says "cannot load such file (LoadError)" - that indicates it's trying to load a spec file, but can't. The file path is `/Users/MrChan/Desktop/matt/week_2/db-drill-ar-student-schema-challenge/source/ar-student-schema/db/spec/student_spec.rb`, so you should check:

- Does the file exist?
- Can you open it?

A common source of this error is trying to run `rspec` within a project subdirectory. When you run `rspec` Rspec looks for a `spec/` directory. If you're in a subdirectory - maybe `db` in this example - then Rspec may look in the wrong place. Given that it seems like you're working through [this code](https://github.com/Uzmani/ar-student-schema), I'm pretty sure that's where the error arose.

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem I had!